# Firebase - typescript compiler doesnt like the firebase twitter authentication

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-security

**Firebase - typescript compiler doesnt like the firebase twitter authentication**

This is when you do: `var auth = this.ref.getAuth();`. Then go: `auth.twitter.id`. The compiler complains about `FirebaseAuthData`.

However, this should be fine because you need to access the twitter id and the code seems to work fine. My version of firebase is: `Firebase v2.3.2`.

Is there a newer version that caters for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current typings on DefinitelyTyped are out of date.

Add the following interface below the FirebaseAuthDataProvider interface:

```
interface FirebaseAuthDataTwitterProvider extends FirebaseAuthDataProvider {
    accessTokenSecret: string;
    username: string;
}
```

Then, update the `FirebaseAuthData` interface to the following:

```
interface FirebaseAuthData {
    uid: string;
    provider: string;
    token: string;
    expires: number;
    auth: Object;
    google?: FirebaseAuthDataProvider;
    facebook?: FirebaseAuthDataProvider;
    twitter?: FirebaseAuthDataTwitterProvider;
}
```

[Or, you can just use this Gist.](https://gist.github.com/davideast/820bec4aa8e525460ced)